# Zend Framework dynamic ACL with special privileges depending on DB entries

Tags: database, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, acl, privileges

I need to implement ACL in a ZF application (with Doctrine 2).

The goal is:
When a user logs in, all his privileges should be determined an saved to memcache, to be accessible quickly throughout the session.

The problem is that there a special privileges the can't be described via module > controller > action.

e.g.

table 'user'

id   name

1     Admin

2     Peter

…

table 'role'

id   name

1     admin

2     user

…

table 'user_role'

id     user_id      role_id

1          1                   1

2       2                  2

…

table 'item'

id     owner

1     1

2     4

…

We have items, which only should be editable by the admin or the user who has created the item (owner).
How could this be described in a privileges table ?

table 'privilege'

id   role_id       …

1     2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertions : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html

Comment: Thanks!
I implemented it with assertions and therefore created assertion classes for each type of resource entity.